# Regression coefficients do not match conditional means

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels

You can download the following data set [from this repo](https://github.com/ArturoSbr/y-u-no-werk).

|  | Y | CONST | T | X1 | X1T | X2 | X2T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.31252 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | -0.836074 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | -0.797183 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I have a dependent variable (`Y`) and three binary columns (`T`, `X1` and `X2`). From this data we can create four groups:

1. `X1 == 0` and `X2 == 0`
2. `X1 == 0` and `X2 == 1`
3. `X1 == 1` and `X2 == 0`
4. `X1 == 1` and `X2 == 1`

Within each group, I want to calculate the difference in the mean of `Y` between observations with `T == 1` and `T == 0`.

I can do so with the following code:

```py
# Libraries
import pandas as pd

# Group by T, X1, X2 and get the mean of Y
t = df.groupby(['T','X1','X2'])['Y'].mean().reset_index()

# Reshape the result and rename the columns
t = t.pivot(index=['X1','X2'], columns='T', values='Y')
t.columns = ['Teq0','Teq1']

# I want to replicate these differences with a regression
t['Teq1'] - t['Teq0']

> X1  X2
> 0   0     0.116175
>     1     0.168791
> 1   0    -0.027278
>     1    -0.147601
```

## Problem

I want to recreate these results with the following regression model (`m`).

```py
# Libraries
from statsmodels.api import OLS

# Fit regression with interaction terms
m = OLS(endog=df['Y'], exog=df[['CONST','T','X1','X1T','X2','X2T']]).fit()

# Estimated values
m.params[['T','X1T','X2T']]

> T      0.162198
> X1T   -0.230372
> X2T   -0.034303
```

I was expecting the coefficients:

1. `T` = 0.116175
2. `T + X1T` = 0.168791
3. `T + X2T` = -0.027278
4. `T + X1T + X2T` = -0.147601

## Question

Why don't the regression coefficients match the results from the first chunk's output (`t['Teq1'] - t['Teq0']`)?

Comment: You have 8 groups in the mean calculation, but only 6 parameters in the regression. I guess two interactions x1:x2 and t:x1:x2 are missing. You could use the formula interface with the 3 way interaction to create the design matrix.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Would you like to post that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: you could write the answer with your corrected example, and accept your answer

Comment: I'll do just that then. I was asking in case you wanted to score an easy +25 rep. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Josef for noticing that `T`, `X1` and `X2` have eight different combinations while my regression model has six parameters. I was therefore missing two interaction terms (and thus two parameters).

Namely, the regression model needs to account for the interaction between `X1` and `X2` as well as the interaction between `X1`, `X2` and `T`.

This can be done by declaring the missing interaction columns and fitting the model:

```py
# Declare missing columns
df = df.assign(X1X2 = df['X1'].multiply(df['X2']),
               X1X2T = df['X1'].multiply(df['X2T']))

# List of independent variables
cols = ['CONST','T','X1','X1T','X2','X2T','X1X2','X1X2T']

# Fit model
m = OLS.fit(endog=df['Y'], exog=df[cols]).fit()
```

Alternatively, we can use the formula interface:

```py
# Declare formula
f = 'Y ~ T + X1 + I(X1*T) + X2 + I(X2*T) + I(X1*X2) + I(X1*X2*T)'

# Fit model
m = OLS.from_formula(formula=f, data=df).fit()
```